# How do I select parts of a string with javascript, add html tag to that or delete parts?

Tags: javascript, string, select, tags, addition

I Have a Paragraph and want to select the first line that ends with a ! or . or ? and give it a header tag.

Than at the end of the paragraph I want to select the words that start with a # and make them disappear.

```
<p>
  Lorem ipsum!
  Dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean 
  commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque 
  penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus 
  mus. Donec quam felis. 
  #sociis #natoque #penatibus #magnis
</p>
```

Should be:

```
<p>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum!</h1>
  Dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean 
  commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque 
  penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus 
  mus. Donec quam felis. 
</p>
```

This is what I have found so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/3ZKP9/37/

**UPDATED**
The working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZKP9/105/

**UPDATE 2**
Working on all paragraphs http://jsfiddle.net/florisvl/3ZKP9/192/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for what you want, given the variable paragraph is your p tag.

```
// 1. Get the text
// Could also use p.innerText but node.data is faster.
var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var text = paragraph.childNodes[0].data;

// 2. Remove all words starting with #
// By using 'g' in the reg exp it will replace 
// all matches not just the first
// This replaces words like ' #foo', and '#bar '
text = text.replace(/( #\w*)|(#\w* )/g, '');

// 3. Surround the first line ending 
// with a '.' or '!' or '?' with h1s
text = text.replace(/([^\n]*?[.!?])/, '<h1>$1</h1>');

// 4. Update p
paragraph.innerHTML = text;
```

I hope that helps

Comment: Hi Julian! Thnx for your response! I am trying to make it work but have no progress at all.. I tried your code in http://jsfiddle.net/3ZKP9/99/.

Comment: Hi, I missed a character, the first '?' in step 3, also your js fiddle works fine once you add the extra slash to the first line e.g. // 1 not / 1, and add var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];You have to set the variable paragraph to the paragraph in the DOM.

Comment: Great Julian! Thank you so much! It works! Learned a bit more!

Comment: Last thing..how can I make sure it works on all paragraphs, not just the one? http://jsfiddle.net/3ZKP9/157/

Comment: No problem. Let me help you out again.

You need to select the paragraphs you want, and then iterate over them and execute the code each of them.

If you want to do this on all paragraphs then first you need to select them all:

    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

This returns a list of all the paragraphs, and now you need to iterate over the list and execute the code above on each paragraph using a loop like so:

    for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; ++i) {
        var paragraph = paragraphs[i];

        // add line 2, 3, and 4
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString = "!Hello!";
var coolioString = myString.replace("!", "<h1>")
var coolioString1 = coolioString.replace("!", "</h1>")
console.log(coolioString1)
```

Like this?